# Flutter mute a sound when device ringer is off

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-ios, flutter-android

In my app, I only want to play a sound when the device ringer is on. Currently the code I have works, but there is a delay for retrieving the device's current ringer status. I am using the audioplayers and sound_mode packages to do this.

```
  _playSound(String sound) async {
       String ringerStatus = await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;
       if (ringerStatus.contains("Normal Mode")) {
            return await player.play(sound);
       }
  }
```

Edit: The problem is that in iOS you have to read the ringer status twice per the [sound_mode package documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_mode) package

From the docs , you can do

```
await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;
```

Comment: This is what I’m using, however there is a delay when I change my ringer midway through the app running and it does not reflect the current ringer status in time. For example, when I set my ringer from normal to silent, it will not reflect the change on the first iteration of the _playSound() function, but it will on the next iteration.